# "Error: parameter name omitted" and passing input file as argument

Tags: c, function, struct, parameters

Okay, so I've been grinding my brains against pavement trying to figure out exactly what parameter name is being omitted. This is my only error, warning or note I'm getting from my build messages.

the line

```
void readTickets(struct tickets_s, int earlyTix, int doorTix) {
```

as part of

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

//Establishing maximum size of array values
#define MAXSIZE 100
#define NUMDRINKS 10
#define MAXPRIZES 100
#define MAXGUESTS 1000
#define MAXRAFFLE 100000

//Establishing struct related to variables for tickets to the ball
struct tickets_s {
    double prePrice;
    double doorPrice;
    double guests[MAXGUESTS];
    int totalTix;
};

//Establishing struct for drink variables
struct drinks_s {
    int drinks[NUMDRINKS];
    double drinkPrices[NUMDRINKS];
};

//Establishing struct for variables related to the raffle
struct raffle_s {
    int raffleGuests[MAXRAFFLE];
    int prizeCount[MAXPRIZES];
    double itemValue[MAXPRIZES];
    double rafflePrice;
};

//Vars for amount of pre-sale tickets, door sale tickets and the totals for drinks, raffle and revenue
FILE* ifp;
int earlyTix, doorTix;
double totalDrinks;
double totalRaffle;
double totalRevenue;

//Renaming structs
struct tickets_s tickets;
struct drinks_s drinks;
struct raffle_s raffle;

void readTickets(struct tickets_s, int earlyTix, int doorTix);

int main() {

    char fileName[MAXSIZE];

    printf("Enter the name of the input file (including file extension)\n");
    scanf("%s", fileName);

    fopen(fileName, "r");
    readTickets(tickets,earlyTix,doorTix);

}

void readTickets(struct tickets_s, int earlyTix, int doorTix) {

    fscanf(ifp, "%d%d", &tickets.prePrice, &tickets.doorPrice);
}
```

I have no clue what this parameter name omission is that it's speaking of. The struct parameter is there. The proper name is used and everything. My compiler has been funky all day, is this just a side-effect?

Also, for some reason I can't pass "ifp" as an argument in the function so I can read data from the input file in said function. I've been trying to get that to work as well but nothing I do is working.

Comment: Did you mean `void readTickets(struct tickets_s TICKETS, int earlyTix, int doorTix)`?

Comment: ?? How in the world did that cause everything to work?

Comment: `struct tickets_s` is a type of the argument, argument itself is missing. Perhaps you meant `struct tickets_s tickets`. I used CAPS just to emphasize. But even if you use `TICKETS`, it works because you have global variable `tickets`.

Answer (score 0):

Commenter AlexD helped me out with a silly mistake I overlooked. Thank you Alex.

"Did you mean void readTickets(struct tickets_s TICKETS, int earlyTix, int doorTix)? - AlexD"

Comment: There is another small point. If you have `struct tickets_s tickets`, it is passed by value. So changing it within `readTickets` does not change the value of passed parameter. Try passing by pointer instead. (Ditto for other `readTickets` arguments.)

Comment: Yes, `void readTickets(struct tickets_s * tickets, int * earlyTix, int * doorTix)`. Then `fscanf(ifp, "%d%d", &(tickets->prePrice), &(tickets->doorPrice));` And `readTickets(&tickets...)`.

Comment: @user3579841 Regarding `earlyTix` and `doorTix`. In previous comment, I meant pass them by pointer _if you want to change them within the function_. Currently they are not used.

Comment: Okay perfect, I think I figured that out earlier but I took those tidbits of code out just to focus on the issue at hand. But thank you so much.